# resolution of attached widescreen

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, monitors, xrandr, resolution

I wanted to connect my TV (Sony Bravia) to my Laptop. My laptop has a displayport and the TV a HDMI. So with the adapters, I'm able to connect those two, and that part works.

What doesn't work, is both screen are widescreen, but it does configure both of them automatically (Kubuntu 12.04) as 1048x768. With the gui tools of Kubuntu, it doesn't even give me the choice to change the resolution to a widescreen one.

xrandr gives me the following output:

```
    xrandr --query
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
    LVDS1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 287mm x 180mm
       1440x900       60.0*+   59.9     50.0  
       1360x768       59.8     60.0  
       1152x864       60.0  
       1024x768       60.0  
       800x600        60.3     56.2  
       640x480        59.9  
    VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)         1600mm x 900mm
       1920x1080      60.0 +
       1280x1024      60.0  
       1280x720       60.0  
       1024x768       60.0* 
       800x600        60.3  
       640x480        60.0
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

KDE doesn't remember how you want inputs setup if they're not connected at start-up (AFAIK), but if you just want the `xrandr` fix:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of LVDS1
```

This will set both outputs to the preferred mode (the one with the "+") and put the TV out to the left of your laptop screen (change `--left-of` to whatever you need: `right-of`, `below`, `above`, `same-as`).